# Create a Bowtie Pattern with Python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a odd positive integer h, greater than or equal to 5, create a bowtie pattern with h rows and 2h columns.

```
input: 5
output:

*        *
***    ***
**********
***    ***
*        *
```

or

```
input: 7
output: 
*            *
***        ***
*****    *****
**************
*****    *****
***        ***
*            *
```

I created code that only works for one given value of h but I'm not sure how to make it functional for any value of h. I also tried taking advantage of the symmetry so I made only half of the bowtie.

```
h = input()
n = int(h)
x = "*"
space = " "
print(x)
print(-(-n // 2)*x)
print(n*x)
print(-(-n // 2)*x)
print(x)
```

Comment: Hint: use `str.center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build up the top half by left and right justifying the `*` repeated as many times as necessary (we use `range` with a step for this as the first row will have 1 `*`, the next 2 more, the next 2 more again up until we reach N) padded left and right with width `n`, eg:

```
n = int(input())
top = [('*' * i).ljust(n) + ('*' * i).rjust(n) for i in range(1, n, 2)]
```

This gives you a `top` (for n=5)  of:

```
['*        *', '***    ***']
```

Then, we print the top, the middle (which is always `*` repeated N*2 times) and then top in reverse order for the bottom separated by newlines, eg:

```
print(*top, '*' * n * 2, *reversed(top), sep='\n')
```

Gives you (n=5):

```
*        *
***    ***
**********
***    ***
*        *
```

Or for (n=11):

```
*                    *
***                ***
*****            *****
*******        *******
*********    *********
**********************
*********    *********
*******        *******
*****            *****
***                ***
*                    *
```

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry tells you that the left and the right have the same number of `*`. It also tells you that the middle row is *all* stars (`n * 2`), and that each row the same distance above and below the middle row has the same size. Further, as you move away from the center, you lose 4 stars total, 2 from each side.

The two secrets to coding this concise are to 1) number the rows symmetrical, not from 1 to `n`, but from `-n//2` to `n//2`; and 2) to think of the rows as a number of *spaces* drawn on a background of `*`s, rather than a number of `*`s surrounding spaces.

Once you figure out how many spaces are in each row (call it `f(i)`, based on the value of `i` in `for i in range(-n//2, n//2+1): ...`, you can draw that row with `(" "*f(i)).center(2*n, "*")`.

Answer (score 1):

it will work for any odd number

```
h = input()
n = int(h)
i = 1
if(n%2)!=0 and n > 4:
    halfmark= n//2
    str=""
    while i <= n:
        if(i<=halfmark):
            blank = ' '* (4*(halfmark +1-i))
        elif i > (halfmark+1):
            blank = ' '*(4*(i-(halfmark+1)))
        else:
            blank = ''

        star  = '*'*((2*n-len(blank))//2)
        str = star+blank+star
        print(str)
        i +=1
```